# How to run cinnamon properly?

Tags: linux-mint, graphics, cinnamon

I am running cinnamon fallback, the output of `inxi -SGx` is

```
System:    Host: elie-Hp Kernel: 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.6.3) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Linux Mint 13 Maya
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           X.Org: 1.11.3 drivers: vesa,intel (unloaded: fbdev) Resolution: 1368x768@0.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A Direct Rendering: N/A
```

Is there a chance that i can run cinnamon properly and not in fallbak mode?